# Trying to program trading signals in R

Tags: r

I new new to R and am trying to program a pair trading strategy in R. 
I have already written the code for downloading the data. And have created additional columns and prepared the data. Now i need to calculate the trading signals.
My signal rules are as follows.
-   If Z-Score is greater than 2.25 , Sell the pair; Buy back when Z-Score is less than 0.25.
-   If Z-Score is less than -2.25 , Buy the pair; sell (Exit) when z-score is above -0.25.
-   close any open position if there is a change in signal.

When we sell a pair, we sell the first stock and buy the second stock. In this case, we sell ACC and Buy Ambujacem.
When we buy a pair, we buy the first stock and sell the second stock. In this case, we buy ACC and Sell Ambujacem.
Could anyone help me with the coding for the trading signals.
Enclosing the code.

Regards,
Subash

```r
# Trading Code

library(quantmod)

getSymbols("ACC.NS", from=as.Date('2007-01-01'), to=as.Date('2015-07-24'))

getSymbols("AMBUJACEM.NS", from=as.Date('2007-01-01'), to=as.Date('2015-07-24'))

acc=ACC.NS[,6]

amb=AMBUJACEM.NS[,6]

t.zoo <- merge(acc, amb, all=TRUE)

t.zoo=as.data.frame(t.zoo)

typeof(t.zoo)

t.zoo=na.omit(t.zoo)

#adding columns

t.zoo$spread <- 0

t.zoo$adfTest <- 0

t.zoo$mean <- 0

t.zoo$stdev <- 0

t.zoo$zScore <- 0

t.zoo$signal <- 0

t.zoo$BuyPrice <- 0

t.zoo$SellPrice <- 0

t.zoo$LongReturn <- 0

t.zoo$ShortReturn <- 0

t.zoo$Slippage <- 0

t.zoo$TotalReturn <- 0

#preparing the data
#Calculating the pair ratio
t.zoo$pairRatio <- t.zoo$ACC.NS.Adjusted/t.zoo$AMBUJACEM.NS.Adjusted


#Calculate the log prices of the two time series
t.zoo$LogA <- log10(t.zoo$ACC.NS.Adjusted)

t.zoo$LogB <- log10(t.zoo$AMBUJACEM.NS.Adjusted)

#Calculating the spread
t.zoo$spread <- t.zoo$ACC.NS.Adjusted/t.zoo$AMBUJACEM.NS.Adjusted

#Calculating the mean
# Computes the mean using the SMA function
# choose the number of days for calculating the mean
SMAdays = 20

t.zoo$mean <- SMA(t.zoo$spread,SMAdays)

#Calculating the Std Deviation
t.zoo$stdev <- rollapply(t.zoo$spread,20,sd, fill=NA, align='right')

#Calculating the Z Score
t.zoo$zScore <- (t.zoo$pairRatio - t.zoo$mean)/t.zoo$spread

View(t.zoo)

#Calculation of trading signals and trading prices
#Trigger sell or buy signal if Z Score moves above 2.25 or below -2.25.
# Close position if Z Score reaches 0.2 or -0.2.

# close any open position if there is a change in signal.
```

Comment: It seems to mean the region between -0.25 and + 0.25 is always buy and region outside -2.25 and +2.25 is always sell. The region between 0.25 and 2.25 on both sides in ambiguous.   What does the line `close any open position if there is a change in signal` mean?

Comment: What i meant is that if the Z score moves above 2.25 it is a sell. We then buy back this position when the Z score decreases to 0.2 or below.

Comment: If Z score moves below -2.25 it is a buy. We then square up this position when the Z score moves to -0.2 or above..

Comment: If there is a buy position, we must close this position before initiating any fresh sell.

Comment: I have tried to do some coding myself. I am however getting some errors. Could anyone help.

Comment: Following from  the code given above, I typed the following code for generating the trading signals.

Comment: # To count number of rows in the data set.
n = nrow(t.zoo)
ntotal = n
nstart = SMAdays

# The rule to enter into the trade and to exit is coded below
for (i in nstart:ntotal){
  if (t.zoo$zScore[i] >= 2.25 && t.zoo$signal=0) {
    t.zoo$signal = "Sell"
    t.zoo$BuyPrice = t.zoo$AMBUJACEM.NS.Adjusted
    t.zoo$SellPrice = t.zoo$ACC.NS.Adjusted
  } else if (t.zoo$zScore [i] <= -2.25 && t.zoo$signal=0) {
    t.zoo$signal = "Buy"
    t.zoo$BuyPrice = t.zoo$ACC.NS.Adjusted
    t.zoo$SellPrice = t.zoo$AMBUJACEM.NS.Adjusted
  } else if (t.zoo$zScore <= 0.25 && t.zoo$signal=1) {

Comment: t.zoo$signal = "Close Sell position"
    t.zoo$BuyPrice = t.zoo$ACC.NS.Adjusted
    t.zoo$SellPrice = t.zoo$AMBUJACEM.NS.Adjusted
  } else if (t.zoo$zScore >= -0.25 && t.zoo$signal=1) {
    t.zoo$signal = "Close Buy position"
    t.zoo$BuyPrice = t.zoo$ACC.NS.Adjusted
    t.zoo$SellPrice = t.zoo$AMBUJACEM.NS.Adjusted
  }

Comment: I am getting error unexpected messages when i run the above code.

Comment: I'd revert in the  evening .

Comment: meanwhile , can you do a `hist(t.zoo$zScore) ` and see if levels qualify to trigger enough trades? Also, it would be great if you could send a link to an online  description of this strategy .

Answer (score 0):

I think  the main issue was to come up with trading signals for a strategy that depends not only on the current level of indicator but also on the direction from which the indicator is crossed.

There were a number of problems with the code posted in comments, including use of single `=` for comparisons .  So I've worked it afresh

Here's my attempt at solving this. It seems to be fine. I've added some plotting code to eyeball the results. I suggest you check the result over different periods.

This code comes after the one in the original question . Only difference is that I have **kept `t.zoo` as an xts/zoo object** and **not** converted it to data.frame. Also, I've multiplied `zScores` with 100

It generates trigger dates  and also a column depicting the state of strategy. Calculating returns would be easy from there

```
colnames(t.zoo)
#t.zoo must be an xts object 

#working on a separate xts object    
sigs<- t.zoo[, c("ACC.NS.Adjusted",       "AMBUJACEM.NS.Adjusted" , "zScore")]

# creating my own triggers as there are not enough good values
# buyTrig<- mean(t.zoo$zScore ,na.rm = T) - 1*sd(t.zoo$zScore ,na.rm = T)
# sellTrig<- (-1) * buyTrig
# sqOffTrig<- mean(t.zoo$zScore ,na.rm = T) - 0.5*sd(t.zoo$zScore ,na.rm = T)

# Another approach: scaling tz.zoo to fit your criterion
sigs$zScore<- sigs$zScore*100

buyTrig<- (-2.25)
sellTrig<- (-1) * buyTrig
sqOffTrig<- 0.25 
cat ( buyTrig, sellTrig , sqOffTrig)

hist(sigs$zScore, breaks = 40)
abline(v=c(buyTrig,sellTrig), col="red")
abline(v=c(-sqOffTrig, sqOffTrig), col="green")

sum(sigs$zScore >= -sqOffTrig  & sigs$zScore<= sqOffTrig  , na.rm = T) # 139

sigs$action<- 0
sigs$mode <- NA


sigs$zLag<- lag.xts(sigs$zScore,1)
sigs[19:22,]

#these are not the real trigger dates, but they will serve our purpose
# along with na.locf 

buyTrigDays<- time(sigs[sigs$zScore<= buyTrig & sigs$zLag > buyTrig,  ])
sellTrigDays<- time(sigs[sigs$zScore>= sellTrig & sigs$zLag < sellTrig,  ])

#square offs
buySqOffDays<- time( sigs[sigs$zScore>= (-1*sqOffTrig) & sigs$zLag < (-1*sqOffTrig),  ] ) 
buySqOffDays
sellSqOffDays<- time( sigs[sigs$zScore<= (sqOffTrig) & sigs$zLag > (sqOffTrig),  ] ) 
sellSqOffDays

sigs$mode[buyTrigDays]=1 ; sigs$mode[sellTrigDays]= -1;
sigs$mode[buySqOffDays]=0 ; sigs$mode[sellSqOffDays]= 0;

sigs$mode

# use local fill to repeat these triggered position into future 
# till you meet another non NA value 

sigs$mode<- na.locf(sigs$mode, fromLast = F)

plot((sigs$zScore["2015"] ))
points(sigs$zScore[sigs$mode==1], col="red", on=1, pch = 19)
points(sigs$zScore[sigs$mode==-1], col="green", on=1 , pch = 19)
points(sigs$zScore[sigs$mode==0], col="blue", on=1)

sum(is.na(sigs$mode))

#now  to get the real dates when square off is triggered

trigdays<- time( sigs[diff(sigs$mode,1) != 0, ] ) #when the value changes

squareOffTrigger_real<- time(sigs[sigs$mode==0][trigdays])
buyTrigger_real<- time(sigs[sigs$mode==1] [trigdays])
sellTrigger_real<- time(sigs[sigs$mode==-1][trigdays])

#check
length(sellTrigger_real) + length(buyTrigger_real) == length(squareOffTrigger_real)


plot(sigs$zScore["2015"])
points(sigs$zScore[buyTrigger_real]  , col="blue", pch = 19, on=1)
points(sigs$zScore[sellTrigger_real]  , col="red", pch = 19, on=1)
points(sigs$zScore[squareOffTrigger_real]  , col="green", pch = 19, on=1)
abline(h=c(-sqOffTrig, sqOffTrig) , col= "green" )

# further calculations can  be easily made using either the mode 
# column or the trigger dates computed at the end
```

Comment: Below are two links to give a better understanding of the pair trading strategy. http://www.quantinsti.com/blog/statistics-behind-pair-trading-ii-entry-and-exit-points/

Comment: http://www.quantinsti.com/blog/statistics-behind-pair-trading-i-understanding-correlation-and-cointegration/

Comment: one more link for mbetter understanding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairs_trade

Comment: Interesting. Will try it some time. Did you run my code and check the result ?

Comment: This will be of interest. http://www.rfortraders.com/lecture-4-regression-and-pairs-trading/ It is a standard TA technique, so other material is also available https://www.r-bloggers.com/pairs-trading-issues/